# Apply CSS properties to class but only if element has another specific class

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
 <li class="arrow branches"></li>
 <li class="arrow branches"></li>
 <li class="arrow branches"></li>

 <li class="arrow"></li>
 <li class="arrow"></li>
 <li class="arrow"></li>
```

I want to give css commands only for "arrow branches" classes,how can I give them css that wont effect the "arrow" classes?

Answer (score 4):

Create the class `.branches`:

```
.branches{
    color:#f00;
}
```

If you want to apply it to only those elements that have branches and arrows then put them together:

```
.arrow.branches{
    color:#f00;
}
```

But if you want to apply it to more than one class thats easy too:

```
.branches, .otherClass{
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: but I want css to point to the arrow of the branches only,and not to effect the arrow,I also want not to approach only branches

Comment: I updated my question. The `.branches` and `.arrow` are given to the same three elements, what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely simple:

```
li.arrow.branches
{...styles...}
```

This selects LI elements with the classes branches AND arrow, but not arrow on its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
.arrow.branches { // your css }
```

Works only for elements with both classes.